# Загрузка изображений

Tags: php, изображения

Здравствуйте, есть форма загрузки изображения, все работает, но хотелось, чтобы у каждой фотки было название, как и ID в базе, чтобы не было совпадений в названиях. Допустим, загружаю фотку eqwb312beqw.jpg и она сразу переименовывается в 315.jpg.

Answer (score 2):

```
mysql_insert_id()
```

Функция возвращает последний присвоенный айдишник при INSERT запросе. То что надо?

**Дополнено.**

Функцию надо вызвать сразу после инсерта. Если же надо отдельно хранить название изображения, стоит при запросе делать подзапрос:

```
function filename_extension($filename) {
 $pos = strrpos($filename, '.');
 if($pos===false) {
     return false;
 } else {
     return substr($filename, $pos);
 }
}
$extension = filename_extension($picname);
$res = mysql_query ("INSERT INTO images (name,checked,userID,preview) VALUES (concat((SELECT (LAST_INSERT_ID()+1)),'$extension'),'1','$row1[id]',concat((SELECT (LAST_INSERT_ID()+1)),'$extension'))");
```

Comment: Как её использовывать??
у меня есть код
$res = mysql_query ("INSERT INTO images (name,checked,userID,preview) VALUES ('$picname','1','$row1[id]','$picname')");

Comment: Функцию надо вызвать сразу после инсерта.
Если же надо отдельно хранить название изображения, стоит при запросе делать подзапрос:

    function filename_extension($filename) {
     $pos = strrpos($filename, '.');
     if($pos===false) {
         return false;
     } else {
         return substr($filename, $pos);
     }
    }
    $extension = filename_extension($picname);
    $res = mysql_query ("INSERT INTO images (name,checked,userID,preview) VALUES (concat((SELECT (LAST_INSERT_ID()+1)),'$extension'),'1','$row1[id]',concat((SELECT (LAST_INSERT_ID()+1)),'$extension'))");

Answer (score 0):

запоминайте в файле/базе номер. при каждой новой загрузке увеличивайте на 1 и не забывайте обновлять в файле/базе.

Comment: зачем мне увеличивать) я хочу что бы все было автоматом, потому что фотки не я один загружаю,а разные люди и в любое время суток

Comment: ну так, код нужно дописать. а просто так автоматом ничего не бывает.

Answer (score 0):

Вставляете в БД сторочку со всеми данными (путь к картинке, другая инфа итд). Дергаете Id последнего INSERT. и копируете картинку в то место которое указали в таблице с названием ID.jpg - к примеру.

Answer (score 0):

Я вообще предпочитаю прсваивать имя изображениям аля - `microtime().'.'.$type;`

Повторений не будет 100%

```
$imageinfo = getimagesize($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']);
$type = strtr($imageinfo['mime'], array(
"image/gif" => "gif",
"image/jpeg" => "jpg",
"image/png" => "png",
));

$uploadfile = microtime().'.'.$type;
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], 'uploads/'.$uploadfile);
```

Comment: Будет. При большом потоке посетителей есть шанс, что они одновременно грузанут изображения.

Comment: Ога, при этом фаза луны будет полной а меркурий будет ближе обычного к земле =) не несите чуши.
такое возможно только в теории(если все китайцы вдруг захотят позагружать картинки на вашем сайте) =) проверено, совпадений не будет.

Comment: microtime()."_".$user_id.".".$type

Comment: вот мне тоже вариант с microtime() больше по душе. Только не просто микротайм, а примерно так microtime().'_'.$_POST['file']['filename'].$_POST['file']['type']

Comment: Плюс небольшая функция, переписывающая кирилицу на латиницу в $filename.

Не забывайте разделять по папкам, ибо линуксы в одной папке более 30000 (не точно!) файлов не записывают.

Comment: md5(microtime().rand(0,9999999999))

Comment: md5(uniqid(rand(),1))

Comment: тогда уж:

for($i=0; $i<=9999999999; $i++;){
$rand[$i]=rand(0,9999999999999999);
}
$index = rand(0,9999999999);
$uploadfile = microtime().md5($rand[$index]).'.'.$type;

Comment: через md5 генерируется много символов,я изначально написал что хочу присваивать имя по ID,подсказали идею через mysql_insert_id() как реализовать?

Answer (score 0):

По идее нужно по имени выдернуть ID

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT user FROM * WHERE $user");
```

После выдернуть ID из запроса и всё.